# Make message box of zenity scalable?

Tags: zenity

When output contains lots of lines, `zenity --info --text` doesn't make it scale-able, and `zenity --text-info` only accept output from a file.

What can I do now? Maybe other zenity like utility can help?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean with:

> and `zenity --text-info` only accept output from a file

Here is a command producing many lines of output:

```
ls -l /usr/bin | wc -l
1726
```

You just pipe it to `zenity`:

```
ls -l /usr/bin | zenity --text-info --height=500 --width=400
```

or:

```
zenity --text-info --height=500 --width=400 < <(ls -l /usr/bin)
```

The result is definitely a scalable message box:

[image]

Comment: works great for me!